# Assigning elements of system.object class C#

Tags: c#

I have a system.object like this:

```
object paramNames = new object[]
        {
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
        };
```

I am trying to assign the values and I need to do it in a loop instead of doing it manually,so sth like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputcount; i++)
        {
            paramNames[i] = int.Parse(textreader.ReadLine());
        }
```

But I face this error : cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'.
I really appreciate it if you can help me!

Comment: `object[] paramNames`

Comment: `var paramNames = new object[]`

Comment: Why object[] and not int[]? If you are storing only integers, you should use the most specific type.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do like below:

```
object[] paramNames = new object[]
        {
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
        };
```

or better

```
var paramNames = new int[]
            {
                1,
                2,
                3,
                4,
            };
```

or more better

```
var paramNames = new[]
        {
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you've declare `parmNames` as type `Object`.  You need to declare the variable as type `Object[]`

like so:

```
object[] paramNames = new object[]
        {
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
        };
```

The interesting part is that this: `object[] paramNames = new object[]` is actually legal, because `Object[]` can cast to type `Object`

This means you could also technically fix it like so:

```
((Object[])paramNames)[i] = int.Parse(textreader.ReadLine());
```

You shouldn't do this though, it's less clear, but it shows why the assignment doesn't throw the compiler exception, and the attempted assignment does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as following

```
var paramNames = new List<object>();

for (int i = 0; i < inputcount; i++)
{
    paramNames.Add(int.Parse(textreader.ReadLine()));
}
```